# Mysql sum of two fields from two different table

Tags: mysql

I want to sum of two fields which are from different table acc to `labour_master_id`. But when I get results it shows different result.

Here is what I tried

```
select  labours.labour_master_id, 
    sum(labours.amount_paid), 
    sum(labour_cashcredits.amount_paid) 
FROM labours 
left join labour_cashcredits 
    on labours.labour_master_id=labour_cashcredits.labour_master_id 
group by labours.labour_master_id
```

It may be mapping twice so it shows wrong result.

Now problem is occurring on sum.

Any idea how to do this?

i am having error in this query..please help

```
select  l.labour_master_id, l.amount_paid as payable, cc.amount_paid as paid
                FROM
                (
                  select labour_master_id, sum(amount_paid) amount_paid
                  from labours 
                  group by labour_master_id
                ) l
                left join
                (
                  select labour_master_id, sum(amount_paid) amount_paid
                  from labour_cashcredits 
                  group by labour_master_id
                ) cc
                                left join
                (
                  select name,id
                  from labour_masters
                ) lm
                    on l.labour_master_id=cc.labour_master_id 
on l.labour_master_id=lm.labour_masters.id
```

Comment: why are you using left join here? can you please give data sample?

Comment: because in second table may data exits or not

Comment: sums if data exits in second table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using subqueries to perform the sum in each table:

```
select  l.labour_master_id, 
    l.amount_paid, 
    cc.amount_paid
FROM
(
  select labour_master_id, sum(amount_paid) amount_paid
  from labours 
  group by labour_master_id
) l
left join
(
  select labour_master_id, sum(amount_paid) amount_paid
  from labour_cashcredits 
  group by labour_master_id
) cc
    on l.labour_master_id=cc.labour_master_id
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me .. is there any method to doing without sub-queries?

Comment: @AmandeepKaur You might be able to alter this to only use a subquery on the second table, but IMO it is sometimes easier to use subqueries.

Comment: i also want a labour name form labour masters table in my above query. how to join that table with this sub query???

Comment: @AmandeepKaur you should be able to just join to the other table using the `labour_master_id` to return the name.

Answer (score 0):

use this--

```
      SELECT   labours.labour_master_id, SUM (labours.amount_paid),
     SUM (labour_cashcredits.amount_paid)
  FROM labours,labour_cashcredits
     where labours.labour_master_id = labour_cashcredits.labour_master_id
 GROUP BY labours.labour_master_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you want,

```
select  labours.labour_master_id, 
    sum(ifnull(labours.amount_paid,0))+
    sum(ifnull(labour_cashcredits.amount_paid),0) sum
FROM labours 
left join labour_cashcredits 
    on labours.labour_master_id=labour_cashcredits.labour_master_id 
group by labours.labour_master_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using sub-query for the second SUM:

```
SELECT  labours.labour_master_id, SUM(labours.amount_paid), 
          ( SELECT SUM(amount_paid) FROM labour_cashcredits 
            WHERE labour_master_id = labours.labour_master_id 
            GROUP BY labour_master_id
           ) AS credit_amount_paid
FROM labours
LEFT JOIN labour_cashcredits ON labours.labour_master_id = labour_cashcredits.labour_master_id 
GROUP BY labours.labour_master_id
```